# Nodejs passed values not defined inside script?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Hello my problem here is that passed arrays from the nodejs server are defined outside the script tags, but not inside.

```
<h2> <%= resultsArrayDate[15] %> </h1>
            <h2> <%= resultsArrayTitle[22] %> </h1>
            <h2> <%= resultsArrayLocation[5] %> </h1>

        <table border="2" class="table">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>URL</th>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                for (var i=0; i<resultsArrayDate.length; i++) {

                    document.write("<tr>");
                    document.write("<td>"+ this.resultsArrayTitle[i]+ "</td>");
                    document.write("<td>"+ tresultsArrayDate[i]+ "</td>");
                    document.write("<td>"+ resultsArrayLocation[i]+ "</td>");
                    document.write("</tr>");
                }


            </script>
        </table>`
```

Up where the h2's are, the values print out just fine so I know that they've been passed correctly to the client, but down inside the script where I'm printing the table, I get undefined errors on the arrays.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: resultsArrayDate is not defined
    at results:46`

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your client JS has nothing to do with server JS.  On the client, there are no such variables.

Comment: If you are using EJS to populate your H2 elements, why would you not use EJS to create the table as well?

Comment: Im new to this stuff with node and ejs so I am still pretty confused with it. Im trying to create the table from the arrays with a loop because they have different results each time. Is there some way to do this on the server side?